# What code should be executed after vm exit?

Tags: assembly, virtualization, kvm

This is the testing code for vmlaunch in the Linux kernel. In my understanding, `lea 1f(%%rip), %%rax;` stores the label 1's address to the `%rax`. Then `vmwrite %%rax, %[host_rip];` will write the value of `%rax` to the host rip field in the VMCS. The next `vmlaunch` will enter the VM. My question is, after VM exit, which instruction will be executed? If the `%rip` point to the next instruction to be executed, should the `incq (%%rsp);` or `1: pop %%rax;` be executed next? And what is the function of `incq (%%rsp);` in this snippet?

```
    __asm__ __volatile__("push %%rbp;"
                 "push %%rcx;"
                 "push %%rdx;"
                 "push %%rsi;"
                 "push %%rdi;"
                 "push $0;"
                 "vmwrite %%rsp, %[host_rsp];"
                 "lea 1f(%%rip), %%rax;"
                 "vmwrite %%rax, %[host_rip];"
                 "vmlaunch;"
                 "incq (%%rsp);"
                 "1: pop %%rax;"
                 "pop %%rdi;"
                 "pop %%rsi;"
                 "pop %%rdx;"
                 "pop %%rcx;"
                 "pop %%rbp;"
                 : [ret]"=&a"(ret)
                 : [host_rsp]"r"((uint64_t)HOST_RSP),
                   [host_rip]"r"((uint64_t)HOST_RIP)
                 : "memory", "cc", "rbx", "r8", "r9", "r10",
                   "r11", "r12", "r13", "r14", "r15");
```

Comment: The `incq` is to detect a failed `vmlaunch`. Notice the `push $0` and the `pop %%rax`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I read the blog at 
https://nixhacker.com/developing-hypervisor-from-scratch-part-4/
The author mentioned that "before vmlaunch we are moving the rsp to the HOST_RSP and incq (%%rsp) address to rip so that after vmexit remaining code after vmlaunch will run." It seems his statement is incorrect.